Unable to print to Canon IR AdvanceDX C3835i Ubuntu 24.04
I recently switched my Lenovo thinkpad X1 yoga 4th gen to Ubuntu 24. I use this computer for work and have been unable to print to our main office printer since making the switch. We have two printers at the office and I am able to print to the Canon MF 1643i II in our med office, but not the Canon IR AdvanceDX C3835i. I can see both printers in my printers list in settings, but I am only able to print from the Canon MF.
I have installed cups and checked that it is running which it is. I have pulled up the cups gui at localhost:361 and attempted to login using my name and password for my machine, but it did not work. Now when I try, the admin page does not ask me for credentials and simply says unauthorized. I am hoping for help in getting back access to cups admin page or a workaround to add the printer without the need for the gui. I am most definitely a linux newb in many ways, so please know that I will need some basic hand holding type of guidance. Thank you all in advance!

First, install some dependencies:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcups2t64 libcupsimage2t64 cups-bsd libgtk-3-0t64 libjpeg62 libjbig0 libgcrypt20

Then, download the driver from here. Select Linux 64 bit as the operating system and then download the compressed tar file.
Assuming you downloaded the file to your user's ~/Downloads directory, cd into that directory and then extract the file:
cd ~/Downloads
tar xvf linux-UFRII-drv-v600-m17n-00.tar.gz

Then, cd into the newly extracted directory:
cd linux-UFRII-drv-v600-m17n

and run the install.sh file:
./install.sh

if you get a permission error, then run the install file using sudo:
sudo ./install.sh

Follow the setup instructions and then reboot after successful completion.
Please post any errors.

Thank you so much, mchid! I am able to print to both printers now.

@ThunderLocks If this works, then don't forget to mark this as the accepted solution by clicking the ckeckmark icon to the left.
